# CSS margin issue in IE only

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm using a grid system as a responsive layout for a single webpage on our corporate site ([lexisnexis.stacklaw.com.au](http://lexisnexis.stacklaw.com.au)) and am having some css issues in IE.

The [+]/[-] links that are inserted by jquery are moving 20-30px above where they are supposed to appear. 
If you view the page in FireFox or Chrome, they are exactly right.
How can I fix this?

Another quick question, how can I either make each section's  toggle the changeclass as well or, move the [-] to be up on the same line as the  when expanded?

Comment: Can you explain the quick question a bit ? you want the [+]/[-] to stay at the same place when you open an item ?

Comment: yeah I do...   Or make the sections <h3> expand or contract the section in the same way that the [+]/[-] does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 1st part give `float:left` to the `.sectionShort` rule.

For the second

```
var anchor = $("<a href=\"#\" class=\"read more\">[+]</a>").add($(this).find('h3'))
                .click(function(e){
                    //surpress the normal anchor click events
                    e.preventDefault();
                    //fire off our class switching function
                    doSwitch(thisID);
                }).filter('a');
```

Comment: is that for the first part of the question?  I fixed that by changing sectionShort and sectionLong's "display" from inline-block to block.    Any ideas for the second question?

Comment: perfect!   thanks.
didn't need to add the float:left.   just changed the display like i mentioned